# Trying to trigger the Alert box after 60 seconds. And It won't work

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get this alert to work for the last two hours. I don't know why it would't. Is it even possible for me to make it work right there?

```
class TimerHolder : ObservableObject {
@State var showResults = false
var timer : Timer!
@Published var count = 0
func start() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.count = 0
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
        _ in
       // self.count += 1
       // print(self.count)

        if self.count < 60 {
            self.count += 1
            print(self.count)

        }else{


            _ = Alert(title: Text("Warning"), message: Text("The timer will start as soon as you press OK. "), primaryButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {})
                , secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Not yet.")))
        }
            }
        }
    }





struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `Alert ` should be used in View.Body, not in the dataModel class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are making three lefts to turn right.  The ObservableObject should only be a holder for data.

I seems that it would be better that you do this outside of an ObservableObject and that the Timer is held in a View or a ViewController.

class StartViewController: UIViewController {

var displayTimer:Timer!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //setup the Timer
    displayTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0,
                         target: self,
                         selector: #selector(self.displayTimerFired(_:)),
                         userInfo: nil,
                         repeats: false)

}

@objc func displayTimerFired(_ timer: Timer) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "60 Seconds...", message: "60 Seconds have elapsed.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",  style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //clean up timer
    displayTimer.invalidate()


}
```

}

*EDIT*

Sorry just realized you are using SwiftUI

struct TimerView: View {

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 60, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
             _ = Alert(title: Text("Warning"), message: Text("The timer will start as soon as you press OK. "), primaryButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {})
            , secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Not yet.")))

        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Alert` in SwiftUI should be presented via `.alert` modifier in view hierarchy, so it should be like the following

```
class TimerHolder : ObservableObject {
    var timer : Timer!
    @Published var count = 0
    func start() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.count = 0
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
            _ in
            if (self.count < 60) {
                self.count += 1 // << no views here, only calculations
            }
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

somewhere in view

```
struct DemoView : View {
    @ObservedObject var durationTimer = TimerHolder()

    @State private var showAlert = false // state of presenting alert
    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            Text("\(durationTimer.count) Seconds")
        }
        .onReceive(durationTimer.$count) { count in // << listen for timer
            if count == 60 { // << show alert
                durationTimer.stop()
                self.showAlert = true
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) { // alert section, condition + construction
            Alert(title: Text("Warning"), message: Text("The timer will start as soon as you press OK. "), primaryButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {})
                , secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Not yet.")))
        }
    }
}
```